# Call sphinx indexer from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, sphinx

I have a rather large web application that stores large amounts of data in a MySQL database. I also have a php script which does some work on this data.

Because the work the php script is quite intense I run this on multiple separate servers.
Basically the script programatically downloads a random chunk of the data into its own MySql database, calls the sphinx indexer and then uses sphinx to do some of its work.

The PHP script is run over the CLI and executes indefinitely.

After the script downloads the data into its local database it calls the indexer via:

```
$response = exec("indexer results_combined --rotate");
echo PHP_EOL.$response;
```

And each iteration the response is:

```
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=3631)
```

The issue I am seeing is that the first iteration through the indexer runs, the php uses sphinx to do it's work and it produces results.

However the second time round the indexer reports to have run fine, but any call using the php Sphinx API returns no results.

The sphinx->query() command returns nothing for all queries and sphinx->getLastError() doesn't show anything.

If I restart the script then it works again.
I have even tried putting a delay in after the call to indexer in case there is a delay between the SIGHUP and actually being able to query the index but this does not help.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Many thanks

EDIT:

OK so after I submitted this question I had a brainwave. It would seem that once the indexer is called for a second time the sphinx client needs to be recreated.

This causes a new connection to sphinx which seems to then find data.
I will accept an answer from anyone that can explain why!

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the connection open to searchd, it cant 'restart'. Doing so would break the connection.

So the actual 'rotate' is delayed, until there are no connections open.

But dont know why you get 'nothing' from a query, you should just get old results.